# Documentation for each test case when using "Test Template" (Data Driven)

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

When using "Test Template", how can I set [Documentation] to the generated test cases?

I have a workaround for doing it:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    The Test Logic

*** Test Cases ***    arg1   arg2   documentation
Test Case 1            1      a     Doc of test 1
Test Case 2            2      b     Doc of test 2
Test Case 3            3      c     Doc of test 3


*** Keywords ***
The Test Logic
    [Arguments]        ${arg1}     ${arg2}    ${documentation}
    Set Test Documentation      ${documentation}
    Log Many           ${arg1}      ${arg2}
```

but I think there should be a more native way.
I couldn't find such a way. Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you add your expectations. Right now you're leaving that bit out with only ".. more native .." description.

Comment: @A.Kootstra, when thinking of it again, I am really not sure what I am asking for. The example I brought above and FinlayL's answer are the best we can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution available is along the lines of this.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    The Test Logic

*** Test Cases ***    arg1   arg2
Test Case 1            1      a
Test Case 2            2      b
Test Case 3            3      c


*** Keywords ***
The Test Logic
    [Arguments]        ${arg1}     ${arg2}
    Set Test Documentation      Test case covering scenario of ${arg1} and ${arg2}
    Log Many           ${arg1}      ${arg2}
```